# Adding in a scroll button with Ionic React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic4

I'm trying to add in a button which scrolls to the top of the page, using Ionic React. 
This is part of my code so far -

```
...
function scrollToTop() {
    return document.getElementById("page")!.scrollTop;
}

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
                <IonMenuButton />
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle slot="end">Ionic Template - JB</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent id={"page"}>
        <IonCard  className="welcomeImage">
            <img src="/assets/welcomeBacking.jpg" alt=""/>
            <IonCardHeader>
                <IonCardTitle>Welcome!</IonCardTitle>
                <IonCardSubtitle>To this Ionic Template</IonCardSubtitle>
            </IonCardHeader>
            <IonCardContent>
                Lorem ipsum........
            </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
        {/*Checklist*/}
        <IonList>
            {form.map(({val, isChecked, isDisabled}) => (
                <IonItem key={val}>
                    <IonLabel>{val}</IonLabel>
                    <IonCheckbox slot={"start"} value={val} checked={isChecked} disabled={isDisabled} />
                </IonItem>
                ))}
        </IonList>
          <IonButton onClick={scrollToTop}>Scroll to top</IonButton>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

The `scrollToTop` function should scroll to the to the top of the element with id 'page' but tis doesn't. I don't get any errors when clicking the button, instead nothing at all happens.

I know this is a trivial thing to implement in Angular but I'm having trouble using React for this. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: you can use scroll(0,0) it will scroll to the top of the page !!

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't do anything - maybe the id needs to be moved to another Ionic tag?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with `scrollToTop` method of [IonContent](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content), but you have to enable `scrollEvents` first. In ionic react, the methods can be accessed using `refs`. Doesn't look much reacty but at least this works for now.

```
........    
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const Home: React.FC = (props) => {
    const contentRef = useRef<HTMLIonContentElement | null>(null);
    const scrollToTop= () => {
        contentRef.current && contentRef.current.scrollToTop();
    };
    return (
        .....
        <IonContent ref={contentRef} scrollEvents={true}>
            ................
            <IonButton onClick={()=>scrollToTop()}>Scroll to top</IonButton>
        </IonContent>
        .....
    );
};
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add duration in IonContent's scrollToTop() method.
This is the official signature of the method:

`scrollToTop(duration?: number) => Promise<void>`

So, finally it will be like below:

`const scrollToTop= () => {
        contentRef.current && contentRef.current.scrollToTop(500);
    };`

Comment: it's an optional param

Comment: In my tests, I didn't have to `scrollEvents={true}` (Ionic ^7, React ^18)

Answer (score 0):

```
export const waitForElement = <K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
  sel: K,
  cb: (el: HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]) => void
) => {
  const el = document.querySelector(sel)

  if (!el || !el.offsetHeight) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => waitForElement(sel, cb))
  } else {
    cb(el)
  }
}
//Use this function to scroll top.
export function scrollTop() {

  waitForElement("ion-content", (contentEl) => {
    if (contentEl) {
      contentEl.scrollToTop()
    }
  })
}
```