# window.scrollTo() is not functioning properly in react ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a listing page in my application. When the user searches for any word the list will be displayed accordingly! To achieve this I am using two components(Let's say search and listing). When the search result is found the array will be passed to another component (i.e. listing component).

Now, the scroll-to-top button is not on the listing component. It is on the searching component. I am calling `window.scrollTo(0,0)` But nothing is working!

Here is the code:

```
const scrollToTop = () => {
        window.scrollTo(0,0)
    }

return (
     <div className={`!overflow-y-auto container bg-satin-3 rounded-lg pt-3 pb-6 md:px-3 h-fit xl:pb-3 2xl:pb-2 lg:pb-4`} >
      <ComponentCalled to display the listing />
      <IonButton
         onClick={() => scrollToTop()}
         className="float-right"
       >
       Scroll to Top
       </IonButton>
```

)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding in a scroll button with Ionic React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730178/adding-in-a-scroll-button-with-ionic-react)

Comment: With ionic-content, scroll-to-top starts working! but by using it That component's scrolling is coming additionally! i.e. two scroll bar on the page (the default browser scroll bar and ionic content's scrollbar)

Comment: Try to use scrollToView() on your click event. Here is the link you can refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ls1dwp?file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

I have reuse your code and In my case it's working perfectly as shown below:

`scrollToTop = () => { window.scrollTo(0,0); };`

```
return (
  <div className="css" >
    <p>TOP</p>
    <ComponentCalled name="! I'm working"/>
  
  <button
     onClick={() => this.scrollToTop()}
     className="float-right"
   >
   Scroll to Top
   </button>
   </div>
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vk1fle?file=index.tsx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using ionic react and by using ionic's ionic-content component I am able to achieve the scroll-to-top functionality. But by  doing this I am getting an additional scroll bar i.e. two scroll bar on the page (the default browser scroll bar and ionic content's scrollbar)